# write on customer display with java RXTXComm

Tags: java

I have used this example code to write on customer display but nothing is wrted on it:

```
public class Display2 {

    static  Enumeration       portList;
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static SerialPort         serialPort;
    static OutputStream       outputStream;
    static boolean        outputBufferEmptyFlag = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("SleepWhileInLoop")
 public void StartDisplay() {
    boolean portFound = false;
    String  defaultPort = "COM3";
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();

        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {

         if (portId.getName().equals(defaultPort)) {
            System.out.println("Found port " + defaultPort);
                    portFound = true;

            try {
                System.out.println("current owner : "+portId.getCurrentOwner());
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleWrite", 2000);

            System.out.println("current owner : "+portId.getCurrentOwner());
            } catch (PortInUseException e) {
            System.out.println("Port is offline now.");
            e.printStackTrace();
                        continue;
            } 

            try {
            outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                    }

            try {
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, 
                               SerialPort.DATABITS_8, 
                               SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, 
                               SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                        System.out.println("Display is online now");
            } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {

                    }


            try {
                serialPort.notifyOnOutputEmpty(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error setting event notification");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(-1);
            }


            try {
               Thread.sleep(2000);                          // Be sure data is xferred before closing
            } catch (Exception e) {}

        } 
        } 
    } 

    if (!portFound) {
        System.out.println("port " + defaultPort + " not found.");
    } 
}   
public void ClearDisplay(){
        try{
    outputStream.write(ESCPOS.SELECT_DISPLAY);
        outputStream.write(ESCPOS.VISOR_CLEAR);
        outputStream.write(ESCPOS.VISOR_HOME);
        outputStream.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException e){

        }
}
public void PrintFirstLine(String text){
    try{
    ClearDisplay();
    if(text.length()>20)            //Display can hold only 20 characters per line.Most of displays have 2 lines.
        text=text.substring(0,20);
    outputStream.write(text.getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();

    }
    catch(IOException r){
    }

}
public void PrintSecondLine(String text){
    try{
    outputStream.write(ESCPOS.SELECT_DISPLAY);
    outputStream.write(ESCPOS.Down_Line);
    outputStream.write(ESCPOS.Left_Line);
    if(text.length()>20)
        text=text.substring(0,20);
        outputStream.write(text.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException y){
        System.out.println("Failed to print second line because of :"+y);
    }
}
public void ShowGreeting(){
    String text1="*****Thank You******";                              // 20 characters
    String text2="     Come Again     ";                              //20 characters
    ClearDisplay();
    PrintFirstLine(text1);
    PrintSecondLine(text2);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);                                   //Greeting will dislpay 5 seconds.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Display2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        ClearDisplay();
}
    public void init(){
    try{
     outputStream.write(ESCPOS.Anim);
    }
    catch(IOException i){}
}

public void close(){
     serialPort.close();
     System.exit(1);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
//////////////////////  THIS IS HOW USE THIS CLASS //////////////////////////
    Display2 display=new Display2();
    display.StartDisplay();   //optimal choice is start when system start.
    display.PrintFirstLine("  Java Open Source  ");
    display.PrintSecondLine(" Say Hello TO World ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);     //wait 5 seconds.otherwise unable to see above outputs.   
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Display2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   display.ShowGreeting();
   display.close();     //optimal choice is close when exit from system.


////////////////////// JOIN TO SHARE KNOWLADGE ////////////////////////////////   
}

}
```

I have a wintec pos with embeded customer display 
I have in log

```
Found PORT 3
current owner null
current owner SimpleWrite
Display is online now
```

I have added rxtxParallel.dll and rxtxSerial.dll to java bin folder and RXTXcomm.jar to lib/ext folder

is there anyway to write on it

Comment: Too much code for us. Try to reduce to a small example.

Comment: what do you want to know exaclty from this code

Comment: A 10-line, or so, reduced main() method to display one text only. Anyway, try to catch all Exceptions with a log message. Maybe you get something interessting here.